# What is the name of this optical effect?

Tags: effect

I think effects of this kind are generally called lens flares, but is there a more specific term for this specific effect?[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these your own photos, or someone else's? Do you have any filter on the lens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Diffraction grating

> In optics, a diffraction grating is an optical grating with a periodic structure that diffracts light into several beams travelling in different directions

<sub>[*Wikipedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For me this is combination of flare and starburst which happen when you use high number for aperture and it is caused from diffraction.